# expected value of random variables in coin toss case

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, random-variable

I was reading law of large numbers when I ran into this confusion.

I am asking this doubt in context to coin-toss or dice-throw scenario. We are having i.i.d random variables $X_i$, $X_2$....$X_n$, and we define the sample mean of it as $(X_1 + X_2 + ... X_n)/n$.

What does this sample mean signify ?

Option 1: There are $n$ coins (or dices) and each one of them has been thrown once. We obtained the results and we represent the average of obtained results by sample mean

Option 2: We are having one coin (or  dice) and we toss (or throw) it $n$ times and take the average of whatever values we got and represent it with sample mean.

Is there any other interpretation to this ?

Comment: This is interesting, I think as long as you can assume that opition 1 and option 2 both are i.i.d with  Bournelli distribtuion the results are the same. You will get the same parameters ($p=0.5$). For  option 1 if you assume all other coins are just copies of the first coin, then, it is the same as opion 2, i think